# TypeCasting object to enum doesn't give enum nor error

Tags: java, casting, enums, hashmap, type-conversion

I've an enum of the following type.

```
enum plant{
    rose("r"),lotus("l");

    String label;

    private plant(String label)
    {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

Code :

```
HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
hashMap.put(plant.rose.label,4);
Object object = hashMap;
HashMap<plant, Integer> a = (HashMap<plant, Integer>) object;
System.out.println(a.keySet().contains(plant.rose));
System.out.println(a);
```

Output :

```
false
{r=4}
```

Why is it neither giving any

`ClassCastException` for `HashMap<plant, Integer> a = (HashMap<plant, Integer>) object;`

nor

`true` for `a.keySet().contains(plant.rose)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Generics, once compiled, drop their type parameter, so the typecast is converting a object which is a Hashmap into a Hashmap, there's no runtime error.

As for the comparison, you put the label as hash key, but are comparing it against the actual enum, so it won't be equal.

Comment: isn't "HashMap<plant, Integer> a" supposed to contain "plant" as a key?

Comment: @PankajSinghal yes, but that doesn't modify the keys already in the hashmap, only the types expected on insertion and returned on retrieval; you initially inserted `plant.rose.label` (a `String`) as key, so it doesn't contain `plant.rose` (a `plant`)

Comment: can anything be done to typecast the map's keys to it's corresponding enum without having to iterate through all the enums and converting then?

Comment: @PankajSinghal Not that I can think of, but you *can* use the enum as key, there's no need to use the labels.

Answer (score 0):

your cast actually is casting it to `HashMap` and therefore there is no error.
it have nothing to do with enum. generic types are at compile time. after that u are on your own ;)
maybe this example will help a little

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap();
hashMap.put("ali",4);
Object object = hashMap;
HashMap<Integer, Integer> a = (HashMap<Integer, Integer>) object;
a.put("ali", 123); // compile error
System.out.println(a.keySet().contains("ali")); //true
Set<String> integers = a.keySet(); // compile error
System.out.println(a.get("ali"));
System.out.println(a);
```